# LwM2M: Does Leshan provide persistance?

Tags: eclipse, iot, m2m

I am wondering if the Leshan server can provide persistance.
Let's say I want to store my device reporting information events for some time.
Can I do that using Leshan? or I have to implemented by my self?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Persisting the received data is not in the Leshan scope. You need to do it yourself by listening the incoming data and putting them in a store